# Excel VBA - How can I create (not apply) a filter in a range?

Tags: vba, excel

I have multiple "tables" in the same sheet, I have a dropdown list (Classes, students, teachers) that I use as a menu so when its changed it "redirects" to the cell where the table is in the same sheet, so if I select Classes it goes to cell A2, if I select students it goes to cell A200 and if I select teachers it goes to cell A400.
Since I can create only one filter per sheet, how can I create a filter on the table that has been selected, so if I select Students, a filter is created on the range A2:P350.

This is so when the user selects an option, he doesn't have to manually create a filter on the range but it is created automatically.

I tried Hoja1.Range("A2:P350").AutoFilter, but it doesn't create the filter.

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"? Does it produce an error or something?

Comment: Sorry I just edit it, No errors it just doesn't create the filter.

Comment: hmm. The first time you run a range.autofilter command, it removes the previous autofilter. so maybe you need to run it twice?

Comment: Also, you might want to consider using [tables](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Overview-of-Excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c). That way, you can have multiple autofilters on the same sheet. It has some other nice features too.

Comment: I'm using tables now, its seems it's the only solution....for now

Answer (score 0):

This will filter the second column of the range and select all the values equal to `"abc"`?

```
Hoja1.Range("A2:P350").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="abc"
```

You can record a macro while you manually apply the filter to see what the macro recorder does, then create your own macro using the recorded one as inspiration.

Comment: Good answer but your method applies a filter, I want to create a filter, that means avoid for the user to select the headers of the table and the click filter

Comment: The VBA macro does the job of creating and applying the filter, there is no need for the user to create the filter. What else does "I want to create a filter" mean?

Comment: It doesn't create the filter because the arrows are not shown..."I want to create a filter" means, like I specified in the question, the user doesn't have to manually create a filter on the range but it is created automatically, that means, the user doesn't click in the Home tab, the select the range, then click filter, that means that the macro should display the arrows on the headers automaticly as I changed "views"

Comment: that is exactly what my code does, as you describe. what's wrong with it?

Comment: It's not worng, it's not what I'm looking for, I want to display the filter icons on all the columns but not apply a criteria.